# Read and Write registry entry of type REG_MULTI_SZ using Delphi

Tags: delphi, registry

Delphi offers the library System.Win.Registry to manipulate the windows registry.
Unfortunately it doesn't contain read/write procedures for the registry datatype `REG_MULTI_SZ` (=list of strings).

The following code returns an `ERegistryException` with "invalid datatype" - it seems only to work with datatype REG_SZ:

```
  Registry := TRegistry.Create;
  Registry.RootKey := HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE;
  Registry.OpenKey(cKey, false);
  sValue := Registry.ReadString('MyRegEntry');
```

Meanwhile I am able to read the REG_MULTI_SZ value with

```
  Registry.ReadBinaryData('MyRegEntry', pBuf, sizeof(pBuf));
```

but if I write it back using `WriteBinaryData()` it will be written to the registry as datatype `REG_BINARY` instead of `REG_MULTI_SZ`. So that's not working properly.

How can I manipulate registry data of datatype `REG_MULTI_SZ` using Delphi?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have written two functions (a class helper) to extend the functionality of TRegistry:

```
unit Common.RegistryHelper;

interface

uses
  System.Classes, System.Win.Registry, Winapi.Windows, System.Math;

type
  TRegistryHelper = class helper for TRegistry
  public
    function ReadMultiSz(const name: string; var Strings: TStrings): boolean;
    function WriteMultiSz(const name: string; const value: TStrings): boolean;
  end;

implementation

function TRegistryHelper.ReadMultiSz(const name: string; var Strings: TStrings): boolean;
var
  iSizeInByte: integer;
  Buffer: array of WChar;
  iWCharsInBuffer: integer;
  z: integer;
  sString: string;
begin
  iSizeInByte := GetDataSize(name);
  if iSizeInByte > 0 then begin
    SetLength(Buffer, Floor(iSizeInByte / sizeof(WChar)));
    iWCharsInBuffer := Floor(ReadBinaryData(name, Buffer[0],
      iSizeInByte) / sizeof(WChar));
    sString := '';
    for z := 0 to iWCharsInBuffer do begin
      if Buffer[z] <> #0 then begin
        sString := sString + Buffer[z];
      end else begin
        if sString <> '' then begin
          Strings.Append(sString);
          sString := '';
        end;
      end;
    end;
    result := true;
  end else begin
    result := false;
  end;
end;

function TRegistryHelper.WriteMultiSz(const name: string; const value: TStrings): boolean;
var
  sContent: string;
  x: integer;
begin
  sContent := '';
  for x := 0 to pred(value.Count) do begin
    sContent := sContent + value.Strings[x] + #0;
  end;
  sContent := sContent + #0;
  result := RegSetValueEx(CurrentKey, pchar(name), 0, REG_MULTI_SZ,
    pointer(sContent), Length(sContent)*sizeof(Char)) = 0;
end;

end.
```

Using the functions above you can simply write in your program the following code to add a value to a REG_MULTI_SZ entry:

```
procedure AddValueToRegistry();
const
  cKey = '\SYSTEM\ControlSet001\services\TcSysSrv';
var
  Registry: TRegistry;
  MyList: TStrings;
begin
  Registry := TRegistry.Create;
  Registry.RootKey := HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE;
  Registry.OpenKey(cKey, false);
  try
    MyList := TStringList.Create();
    Registry.ReadMultiSz('MyRegEntry', MyList);
    MyList.Add('NewEntry');
    Registry.WriteMultiSz('MyRegEntry', MyList);
  finally
    MyList.Free;
  end;
  Registry.Free;
end;
```

Comment: It is bad design for `ReadMultiSz()` to return a new `TStringList` object. You are not freeing it if an exception is raised, and the caller can leak it, too. I suggest changing it to take a `TStrings` parameter instead. And I would suggest changing `WriteMultiSz()` to take a `TStrings` instead of `TStringList` as well. These changes will make this helper much more flexible, as they let the caller decide what kind of container to use and how to manage it. Also, `ReadMultiSz()` should dynamically allocate the memory buffer based on the actual size of the data (`TRegistry.GetDataSize()`)

Comment: Also, the inner loop in `WriteMultiSz()` is horribly inefficient. You can replace the entire loop with a single assignment instead: `sContent := sContent + value.Strings[x] + #0;` And you should replace `2` with `sizeof(Char)` in both `ReadMultiSz()` and `WriteMultiSz()`.

Comment: The loop in `ReadMultiSz()` is also pretty inefficient, too. I would suggest using `StrScan()` to search for `#0` characters and `SetString()` to assign complete substrings to `sString`.

Comment: When I try to read from: Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server to read the REG_MULTI_SZ value under InstalledInstances, I get no values back.  The call to iSizeInByte := GetDataSize(name) within ReadMultiSz returns -1, and I'm yet to figure out why.

Comment: Undeclared indentifier error: RegSetValueEx error in delphi rio 10.3.3