# How do I read from registry HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE?

Tags: delphi, delphi-10.3-rio

I'm having a hard time getting any reads from the registry with the root key `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE`.

```
var
  reg : TRegistry;
begin
  Reg := TRegistry.Create();
  Reg.RootKey := HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE;
  if Reg.OpenKey('\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server',false) then
  begin
    Result := reg.ReadString('InstalledInstances');
    ....
```

I'm trying to get the values from the `InstalledInstances` Key:

[image]

At first I thought the code doesn't work. I then tried reading different keys under `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE` with the same results. Is there some kind of permissions thing I'm not getting?

If I use the same code for reading under `HKEY_CURRENT_USER`, that works fine and I get the key values. But under `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE` I can't open any key.

This also doesn't allow me to open:

```
Reg := TRegistry.Create(KEY_ALL_ACCESS);
```

Comment: Likely registry redirector is the problem, unless your process is 64 bit. Possibly you are asking for write access too. Better to use OpenKeyReadOnly.

Answer (score 2):

When reading values from the `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE` root node, you need to use [`TRegistry.OpenKeyReadOnly()`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.Win.Registry.TRegistry.OpenKeyReadOnly) or change the [`TRegistry.Access`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.Win.Registry.TRegistry.Access) property to either `KEY_READ` or `KEY_EXECUTE`. Otherwise, access to the Registry by your application will be blocked by UAC (User Account Control), as it is required to have elevated privileges in order to modify any key under the `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE` root node due to security settings.

Another way is to start your application with elevated privileges (Run As Administrator).

This is not required (although it is still desirable) when reading or modifying the Registry under the `HEY_CURRENT_USER` root node, since the current user already has the needed privileges in order to fully modify its own Registry keys.

EDIT: As for reading or writing REG_MULTI_SZ registry values I recommend you check [Read and Write registry entry of type REG_MULTI_SZ using Delphi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48826844/read-and-write-registry-entry-of-type-reg-multi-sz-using-delphi)

Comment: If I'm not mistaken I have tried KEY_READ, but I will check your solution again tonight when I have time and revert - thank you.

Comment: Ok, KEY_READ & OpenKeyReadOnly both allows me to open the key now which answers the issue of not being able to open the key.  But I'm not getting any value back from reg.ReadString('InstalledInstances').  It just gives me a blank string?  I tried to read another key elsewhere which gives me the value back which is one step further.  Is that something to do with InstalledInstances having a REG_MULTI_SZ type and not a REG_SZ Type?

Comment: As I said in the comments, the registry redirectory is likely to be an issue. I presume your process is 32 bit.

Comment: I have edited my answer to include link to another SO question regarding reading or writing REG_MULTI_ZS registry values. I hope it helps

Comment: I have accepted the answer because I think you answered the question @SilverWarior, but I'm still not able to retrieve that key value.  I think I'll ask a new question regarding that to try and get it sorted.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan, thanx, but I don't know how to know myself if the registry redirectory is the issue or not.  I'm just trying to get a solution...

Comment: Do some research on registry redirection.

Comment: I've removed the above as the answer, because I cannot for example open this path:  Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\CVSM to access the CVSM key.  I've Tried OpenKeyReadonly / KEY_READ / KEY_EXECUTE.  I'll have to find out more if it's not the registry redirection.